# how to insert new patterns in python aiml

Tags: python, aiml

hello i am trying to insert new **patterns** in aiml using python(*aiml library*) i am following this [tutorial](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783287536/9/ch09lvl1sec58/introduction-to-pyaiml), i can use the predefined patterns of A.L.I.C.E chatbot and change the answer of it using the **template** tag but when I insert new pattern which is not in the A.L.I.C.E chatbot the program gives this error ***WARNING: No match found for input: ''***, please help is there a way to insert new patterns using python aiml library?

below is my chatbot.py file

```
    import aiml
    import sys

    mybot = aiml.Kernel()
    mybot.setBotPredicate('name','chefbot')
    mybot.learn('sample.aiml')

    while True:
       if input == "quit":
       sys.exit(0)
       input_text = input("> ")
       response = mybot.respond(input_text)
       print(response)
```

This is my sample.aiml file

```
<aiml version="1.0">
<category>
<pattern>WHY CAN NOT YOU EAT</pattern>
<template>Actually I eat only electricity.</template>
</category>
<category>
<pattern>EACH YEAR IN PRO BASEBALL THE *</pattern>
<template>The Gold Glove.</template>
</category>
<category>
<pattern>hello</pattern>
<template>Hello my friend how are you,i am chefbot</template>
</category>
<category>
<pattern>WHAT IS YOUR NAME</pattern>
<template>My name is chefbot</template>
</category>
<category>
<pattern>YOU CAN DO BETTER</pattern>
<template>Get that cake for me</template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

It gives response to the **patterns** in UpperCase because they are predefined in A.L.I.C.E bot but prints error on **patterns** which I have defined in Lowercase.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All text in between  tags should be in upper case

Every time you modify you aiml files you need to restart your bot

K